# Constructor is not called in RegisterUser trait: Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have constructor in the trait `RegistersUsers`. We can find this trait in below mentioned path

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
```

Here the problem is, Constructor is not being called...Below is the code.

```
private function __construct( \App\Caching\CacheCollection $cacheData )
{
    $this->CacheCollection = $cacheData; 
}
```

Did somebody faced similar issue before ?

Comment: How are you calling RegistersUsers?

Comment: we have inbuilt Registration code in Laravel Template. right ?

Answer (score 1):

If the class that is `use`ing this trait also has a constructor, the constructor provided by the trait will not be used. The override precedence is Class methods override Trait methods which override inherited methods (Class > Trait > Base). If you have a constructor in the class, you need to remove it.

---

A few other notes:

First, if at all possible, you don't want to modify files in the `vendor` directory. Any changes you make in there will be erased the next time you `composer update`, and you won't be able to deploy those changes unless you're committing your `vendor` directory to your repository (not a good idea). You should make a new trait that `use`es this trait, and includes your additional constructor. Then in your classes, use this new trait, not the `RegistersUsers` trait.

Second, you've declared your constructor as `private`. If you do this, you will only be able to create new instances of the class from within the class (such as a static method that creates new instances). I don't know if this was intentional or not, but just letting you know.